# How to shorten mySQL queries with PDO?

Tags: mysql, pdo

I'm new to PDO and try to understand how it works. Here is a snippet to delete a user from the database:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("-- 02 account_delete.php
        DELETE FROM " . TABLE_ADDRESS_BOOK . " WHERE customers_id = :id");
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $_SESSION['customer_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt = $db->prepare("-- 03 account_delete.php
        DELETE FROM " . TABLE_CUSTOMERS . " WHERE customers_id = :id");
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $_SESSION['customer_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt = $db->prepare("-- 04 account_delete.php
        DELETE FROM " . TABLE_CUSTOMERS_INFO . " WHERE customers_info_id = :id  
    ");
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $_SESSION['customer_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
```

How do I shorten it e.g. to combine it into an array or something. I also wonder why I have to repeat the :

```
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $_SESSION['customer_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Otherwise it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I shorten it e.g. to combine it into an array

Just put your queries into array and execute them in a loop.

> I also wonder why I have to repeat binding

Because you're binding a variable to **particular** query. So you can't use it with another.
Anyway, in a loop ypu have to do it only once - so, it doesn't really matter

Comment: Sometime I can't see the wood for the trees. I put the three queries into an array and used a foreach-loop.